# how to separate the selected items in a checkbox?

Tags: c#

I have two forms in WFA C#.

FORM1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                f2.intr = checkBox1.Text;
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
            {
                f2.intr2 = checkBox2.Text;
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
            {
                f2.intr3 = checkBox3.Text;
            }
            if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                f2.intr4 = checkBox4.Text;
            }
            if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
            {
                f2.intr5 = checkBox5.Text;
            }
            f2.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
}
```

FORM2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string gen, intr, intr2, intr3, intr4, intr5;

        public string interest
        {
            get { return intr; }
            set { intr = value; }
        }
        public string interest2
        {
            get { return intr2; }
            set { intr2 = value; }
        }
        public string interest3
        {
            get { return intr3; }
            set { intr3 = value; }
        }
       public string interest4
       {
           get { return intr4; }
           set { intr4 = value; }
       }
       public string interest5
       {
           get { return intr5; }
           set { intr5 = value; }
       }

       public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Interests: " + interest + "\n" + interest2 + "\n"     + interest3 + "\n" + interest4 + "\n" + interest5;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 5 checkboxes inside a groupbox. This outputs the selected items to label1. The output looks like this when I check all the checkboxes:

```
art
science
math
history
sports
```

and whenever I check boxes randomly for example i'll check the art and history. The output is like this:

```
art


history
```

it leaves two spaces.

In the design of form1 there are the checkbox1,checkbox2,checkbox3,checkbox4,checkbox5 inside a groupbox.
In the design of form2 there is only label1.
How can I separate the selected items by a comma in one line?
I'm new to c# helpp.

Comment: All those setters and getters are redundant, you can simplify it with using `public string interest { get; set; }`, `(checkBox1.Checked == true)` is the same as `(checkBox1.Checked)`

Answer (score 4):

You could put all the interests in an array:

```
string[] interests = { interest, interest2, interest3, interest4, interest5 };
```

Then you could remove the non-selected ones:

```
string[] selectedInterests = interests.Where(str => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)).ToArray();
```

At the end you can join them into a single string:

```
label1.Text = String.Join(", ", selectedInterests);
```

Comment: You could remove the assigning of selectedInterests and do that directly in the Join method...

Comment: No he shouldn't. This way it's more readable and easy to maintain when using Debugger. We're not trying to make the shortest code, but the easiest to read and debug.